# could not calculate the dimensions after pooling and subsampling in the famous Convolutional neural nets example

Tags: neural-network, object-recognition, pooling, deep-learning, subsampling

[image: Hierarchical Models Of Perception and Reasoning by Yann LeCun]

The above image is from a pdf by Yann LeCun, titled "Hierarchical Models Of Perception and Reasoning"

**I am not able to understand the how the layer 2 is 14X14 feature maps?
How can 75X75 matrix with 10X10 pooling and 5X5 subsampling gives 14X14 matrix ?**

Comment: Do you know why 64 kernels (from the input to layer 1) produce 64 feature maps while 4096 kernels (layer 2 to layer 3) give 256 feature maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you refer to [this other paper](http://snowbird.djvuzone.org/2009/abstracts/160.pdf) by LeCun et al. an identical network is used with a larger input (143x143 grayscale image):

> The first stage has 64 filters of size 9x9, followed by a subsampling layer with
>   5x5 **stride**, and 10x10 **averaging window**. [...]

This gives the right dimension:

```
output size = (input size - window size) / step + 1
            = (75-10) / 5 + 1
            = 14
```

Comment: Sorry I could not get much from that paper. But if you can help me let me know what will be the matrix size on applying 10X10 pooling on a 75X75 matrix

Comment: There are **two** parameters: 1/ the window size, a.k.a kernel size (= 10) 2/ the stride, a.k.a step (= 5). With a default stride of 1, the 10x10 pooling on a 75x75 matrix gives `75-10+1 = 66` and thus an output matrix of 66x66. With a stride of 5 you get an output matrix of 14x14 (see above). For example please refer to Torch [nn.SpatialSubSampling](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialSubSampling).

Comment: Hey Thank you so much @deltheil for the simple and complete reply :). I got it now. 
But as Hugo Larochelle's deep learning videos on youtube mentions subsampling as pooling without the overlap.
Just wanted to be confirm that the subsampling (5X5) mentioned in the figure above is an stride (step) value, and it is not the case that, first the pooling (10X10) with stride 1 is applied and then subsampling (5X5) is done to reduce the size.

Comment: Hi, @deltheil could you tell me why 64 kernels (from the input to layer 1) produce 64 feature maps while 4096 kernels (layer 2 to layer 3) give 256 feature maps? Thanks!